# Advanced filter working when applied manually, but not working when applied using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a "database" on the Main sheet see below:

[image]

I want to filter out records using DIAMETER column. I need to use 2 AND criteria. So I created another (filter) worksheet with the same columns + one more DIAMETER column - see picture below:

[image]

Formula is below:

[image]

When I apply Advanced filter manually it works:

[image]

However when I apply it using VBA it does not work. I have no idea why. Firstly I wrote custom code, then I also tried to record the macro but it did not work either. It returns empty table.

Code used:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("C22:T42").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("C22:T42").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
        Sheets("filter").Range("B1:T2"), unique:=False
End Sub
```

and part of the custom one (its used in the form):

```
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CONFIG.main_sheet)
    Set filter_ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(CONFIG.filter_sheet)
    
    With ws
        lr = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        col = CONFIG.diameter_col
        lr_f = get_last_row(filter_ws, col)
        
        ' clear all diameters from filter sheet
        If lr_f <> 1 Then filter_ws.Range(filter_ws.Cells(2, col), filter_ws.Cells(lr_f, col)).ClearContents
        
        ' add filter parameters
        filter_ws.Cells(2, col) = "=""<=" & CDec(Me.diameter.value) & """"
        filter_ws.Cells(2, 2) = "="">=" & CDec(Me.diameter.value - 1) & """"
        
        lr_f = filter_ws.Cells(filter_ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).row
        
        ' apply the advanced filter
        On Error Resume Next
        .ShowAllData
        .Range(CONFIG.first_col & CONFIG.first_db_row - 1 & ":" & CONFIG.last_col & lr).AdvancedFilter _
            Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=filter_ws.Range("B1:" & CONFIG.last_col & lr_f), unique:=False
    End With
```

(Ranges in the custom code are correct)

How on earth is this even possible?

Comment: put `Debug.Print CONFIG.first_col & CONFIG.first_db_row - 1 & ":" & CONFIG.last_col & lr` before the advanced filter line and see if the reference makes sense.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned  in the original post - ranges in the custom code are correct (output is `C22:T42`). Also in the first code ranges are static but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

When setting your criteria in diameter, use '**dot**' instead of '**comma**'

[image]

```
Sub advFilter()
    Dim myTable As Range: Set myTable = Sheets("Master").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim myCriteria As Range: Set myCriteria = Sheets("Filter").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
    myTable.AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
        CriteriaRange:=myCriteria, _
        Unique:=False
    
    ' ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: No, not working. My excel uses comma as a decimal separator

Comment: I also use comma as a decimal separator and it worked for me. I will share with you my test file so you can take a look. https://www.dropbox.com/s/2b9p31e5i1gfmop/Advanced_Filter_OR.xlsm?dl=0